# after successfull login i get redirect back to login page MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

my login worked just fine and suddenly it keep redirect me to login page again, even when it's successfull, i did'nt changed anything since it worked an i really can't figure out what's causing this.
any ideas pls?

that's the controller:

```
//Login
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //Login POST
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLogin login, string ReturnUrl= "")
    {

        string message = "";
        using (UsersdbEntities dc=new UsersdbEntities())
        {
            //check if the user and mail are valid in db and correct
            var v = dc.Users.Where(a => a.UserMail == login.UserMail).FirstOrDefault();
            if(v!=null)
            {
                if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(login.PasswordUser), v.PasswordUser) == 0)
                {
                    int timeout = login.RememberMe ? 525600 : 1; //525600 minutes=1 year
                    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login.UserMail, login.RememberMe, timeout);
                    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       return RedirectToAction("PersonalArea", "User");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    message = "invalid credentials";
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                message = "invalid credentials";
            }
        }

        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View();
    }
```

that's the actionresult of personalarea:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult PersonalArea()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: make sure ReturnUrl is not the login page